# Setting the selected item of a Select element

Tags: c#, html, winforms

If I have accessed a Select element on a website, how would I go about changing it's selected item?

I tried:

```
selectElement.SetAttribute("value", "30");
```

But this doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean to put webforms, and not winforms? Just want to clear up possible confusion

Comment: Nope, im accessing the page using winform#s object WebBrowser.

Comment: Could you clarify the question a bit @TheGateKeeper.  I'm not sure what you are trying to get at here.  A select element?  Do you mean a combobox or selectionlist?  Are you trying add new items to it or just change which item it selects?

Comment: See answer below. Sorry for the confusion was in a hurry.

Comment: No problem.  Good quick answer @koenp.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this html

```
​<select id="a">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
​
```

Doing this will select the second option

```
document.getElementById("a").selectedIndex = 1
```

see this jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/vJsvV/